# C++: how to obtain the member element?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to automatically obtain the member element of a class?

For example:

```
class A
{
public:
  int x;
  classB b1, b2;
  ...
};
A a;
vector<classB> bs = a.AllB();
```

I want `a.AllB()` will return `b1, b2`. How can I fullfile this method?

In python, `vars` method will return the member element of a class. Does c++ has the similar method?

Comment: No, you have to write the method manually. You could throw something together using [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), but it's tricky, and works only on a certain subset of classes you could make (if memory serves right, A wouldn't be able to have constructors and non-public data members). Also it can't see the member names, if you need them.

Comment: No not possible at least in C++

Comment: This would require "reflection" which C++ is currently lacking in this area

Comment: `vector<classB> AllB() { return {b1, b2}; }` ?

Comment: Er, structured bindings should be able to do this, no? (On my phone, can't design an example now...)

Comment: Structured binding would work for this MRE, but there is the possibility the question is looking for something more generic that structured binding cannot do.

Comment: Store your member variables in a map instead of directly in the object, e.g. with type `std::variant` or `std::any`, then you can retrieve all member elements of certain types or with certain names.

Comment: @Kevin, @ Dúthomhas The number of member element is flexiable. I want a methond `GetMemberElement` in the super class. Then, in the sub-class, I can automatically obtain all the member elements. As it said from @HolyBlackCat, @BKN, @Cory Kramer. it may be impossible.